# How to write my own annotations in PHP to modify a class

Tags: php, annotations

I need to create my own annotations in PHP. For example

```
@Getters
class Person { 
   private $name;
   private $age;
}
```

@Getters annotation shall generate getters for all fields in the class.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. How will `@Getters` generate all fields....??

Answer (score 1):

Different from Python or other similar languages, PHP's notion of [attribute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.attributes.overview.php) (annotation) is only for code reflection. It is designed to provide meta data of the class instead of actually modifying the class coding or functionality.

I guess you'd have better chance using [magic method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) with [traits](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php):

```php
trait Getters
{
    public function __call(string $name, array $arguments)
    {
        if (str_starts_with($name, 'get')) {
            if (preg_match('/^get([A-Z]{1})(.+?)$/', $name, $matches)) {
                $name = strtolower($matches[1]) . $matches[2];
            }
            if (isset($name)) {
                return $this->{$name};
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class Person {
    use Getters;
    private string $name = "Alice";
    private int $age = 12;
}

$p = new Person();
var_dump($p->getName());
var_dump($p->getAge());
var_dump($p->getNothing());
```

Result:

```
string(5) "Alice"
int(12)
NULL
```

This is not a good idea, thou. Without the actual method implementation, IDEs would have hard time detecting issues of your code. You're better off generate those getter or setter functions with IDE extensions or AI.